# How to find the algorithm of a hash in case of having the plain text?

Tags: hash, hashcode

Is there any way to find the algorithm in case of having the plain text and related hash code together?
This hash seems a little unusual.

$Dpt=HIaHS-mpx#VkK

and the plain text is:

A 20010517 0001-9999-0003 20010720.162031 00019 001 + P C BN * 0 BN + 0

Comment: I would think that logic + mostly brute force would be the only way to go about it.

Comment: The hashcode is not valid Ascii85

Answer (score 0):

Brute force. The point of a hash is that it's one-way. You'll only find out which algorithm was used when you use the same algorithm and get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But by which algorithm I should try Brute force?
The hash and the plain text are both available.

Comment: There are an infinite number of hashing algorithms available. You need to use your knowledge of the domain within which the hash and plain text exist to determine which ones to try.

Comment: Is it possible to guess the type of hash according to the lenght and characters?  or is there any similarity between this and that ones you know?